# Filter by index of nested array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array in javascript which contains a number of nested arrays

```
let data = [
  ["Apple","Fruit","Red"],
  ["Pear","Fruit","Green"],
  ["Orange","Fruit","Orange"],
  ["Carrot","Vegetable","Orange"],
  ["Pea","Vegetable","Green"],
  ["Pumpkin","Vegetable","Orange"]
]
```

From this array, I wish to create two new arrays. `Arr1` is the unique food types (index2) and `Arr2`is the unique colors (Index 3).

My new arrays should be:

```
Arr1 = ["Fruit","Vegetable"]
Arr2 = ["Red","Green","Orange"]
```

I have managed to achieve this by using `for each`, where I've pushed every second object to an array. I then filter this new array for unique values. This is the code I'm using to do this:

```
var Foods = []
var Colors = []

for (var key in data) {
          Foods.push(data[key][1]);
}         


for (var key in data) {
          Colors.push(data[key][2]);
}  


let Arr1 = [...new Set(Foods)]
let Arr2 = [...new Set(Colors)]


console.log(Arr1)
console.log(Arr2)
```

Although this works well, as a javascript beginner, I thought there may be a more elegant way to achieve.

For example is it not possible to filter all the unique values of data with an index of [2]?

Comment: sets are best option when you want to deal with duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine as it is, the only improvement would be to replace loops with `map`:

```
let foods  = [...new Set(data.map(d => d[1]))]
let colors = [...new Set(data.map(d => d[2]))]
```

There's absolutely no need to overcomplicate matters with `reduce`, destructuring and so on.

If you want it to look slightly more elegant, you can define two utility functions

```
const item = i => a => a[i]
const uniq = a => [...new Set(a)]
```

and then

```
let foods  = uniq(data.map(item(1)))
let colors = uniq(data.map(item(2)))
```

Another option:

```
const uniq = a => [...new Set(a)]
const zip = (...args) => args[0].map((_, i) => args.map(a => a[i]))

let [_, foods, colors] = zip(...data).map(uniq)
```

Answer (score 2):

Reduce the array to two Sets, and then destructure the Sets, and spread each into the respective array:

```js
const data = [["Apple","Fruit","Red"],["Pear","Fruit","Green"],["Orange","Fruit","Orange"],["Carrot","Vegetable","Orange"],["Pea","Vegetable","Green"],["Pumpkin","Vegetable","Orange"]]

const [s1, s2] = data.reduce((acc, arr) => {
  acc.forEach((s, i) => s.add(arr[i + 1]))

  return acc
}, [new Set(), new Set()])

const Arr1 = [...s1]
const Arr2 = [...s2]

console.log({ Arr1, Arr2 })
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an object with foods and colors as keys and loop through inserting the appropriate element index each iteration

```js
let data = [
  ["Apple","Fruit","Red"],
  ["Pear","Fruit","Green"],
  ["Orange","Fruit","Orange"],
  ["Carrot","Vegetable","Orange"],
  ["Pea","Vegetable","Green"],
  ["Pumpkin","Vegetable","Orange"]
]

const uniques = {
   foods:new Set(),
   colors: new Set()

}
data.forEach(a => uniques.foods.add(a[1]) && uniques.colors.add(a[2]) )

// just for demo logs
Object.entries(uniques).forEach(([k,set])=> console.log(k,':', ...set))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a single loop and get the unique values for all items of the nested arrays.

```js
const
    getUnique = array => array
        .reduce((r, a) => a.map((v, i) => (r[i] || new Set).add(v)), [])
        .map(s => [...s]),
    data = [["Apple", "Fruit", "Red"], ["Pear", "Fruit", "Green"], ["Orange", "Fruit", "Orange"], ["Carrot", "Vegetable", "Orange"], ["Pea", "Vegetable", "Green"], ["Pumpkin", "Vegetable", "Orange"]],
    [, types, colors] = getUnique(data);
    
console.log(types);
console.log(colors);
```